# Переменная не обнуляется при обновлении страницы

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть переменная `currentpage`, которая увеличивается при прокрутке вниз и подгружаются товары в зависимости от ее значения внутри функции:

```
var currentpage = $('#currentpage').val();
var nextpage = parseInt(currentpage);
$('#currentpage').val(nextpage+1);
```

так вот, при обновлении страницы, к примеру в Firefox, она иногда остается той же и товары начинают подгружаться, к примеру с 20-й страницы. хранится она в

```
<input type='hidden' id='currentpage' value='1'>
```

Comment: Данная ошибка от предоставленных данных не зависит, ищите проблему в другом месте. Возможно на странице используется history, cookies, location или другие вещи, которые запоминают данные.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2):

Принудительно устанавливайте нужное значение в поле при загрузке страницы перед тем, как первый раз присвоить его переменной

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#currentpage').val('1');
    var currentpage = $('#currentpage').val();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Думаю, Ваша проблема связана с тем, что значения инпутов кешируются, например, тем же файрфоксом.

Проблема часто встречается в сети, например [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2486474/preventing-firefox-from-remembering-the-input-value-on-refresh-with-meta-tag)

Скрипт ваш берет значение из поля, которое кешируется.

Самое простое - прикрепить обнуление поля при событии выгрузки (unload) или загрузки (load) страницы.

Answer (score 0):

Вам уже ответили, и как решить проблему и откуда он появляется.

Зачем вы вообще таким образом храните значение?

Если вы хотите чтобы при перезагрузке всё сбрасывалось, то можно хранить просто в глобальной переменной(это простой, но не самый хороший вариант). Либо же создать JS объект и в нём хранить текущее состояние, и при перезагрузке всё будет сбрасываться.

Если же вы вдруг решите, что вам надо запоминать состояние при перезагрузке(или же чтобы у пользователя была возможность передать кому-то ссылку на конкретную страницу). То надо записывать состояние в URL, для этого посмотрите на работу с [History API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API). Только для этого надо будет чтобы сервер так же поддерживал такой формат. Если же вы не хотите, что бы сервер это как либо обрабатывал, то можете при загрузке странице в JS проверять параметр и исходя из его значения выполнять нудные действия(подгружать нужную страницу или первую). Как в JS это делается, можете посмотреть [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/831030/how-to-get-get-request-parameters-in-javascript).

Comment: Я не храню значение. Просто есть поле с именем, которое при его заполнении меняет пароль. А получается так, что пароль сам заполняется и очистить значение никак не удается. И при изменении других полей меняется всегда и пароль.